# Finding an elements within a range using O(n) runtime

Tags: c

I am trying to write a function the receives an array with size "N" from the user, with values between 0--->N-1 the function should return "1" if all the values between 0---->N-1 are there otherwise it returns 0. **we can assume that the numbers that user will input are only valid values. between 0---->N-1.**

Example: N=5,Values: 2,1,4,0,3---->returns 1, 
         N=5,values: 2,3,4,0,3---->returns 0

I tried various ways to solve this problem.

thought about a factorial, but find that there are many ways to get the same factorial using duplicate numbers and unique numbers. also thought about sum the numbers, but still too many ways to get the same answer. Is there any way, to be sure I have only unique items without subarray?

WE CANT USE SUBARRAY(another counter array etc.), AND THE FUNCTION SHOULD RUN O(n).

Comment: `O(n)` for _unsorted_ elements 0->N-1 without a way to store values encountered in a table seems ambitious. I'm curious about the solution too...

Comment: can you show examples when "the values aren't there" ? "the values are here" ? what happens? duplicate zeroes? values > N ?

Comment: for example: N=5 values are: 2,1,4,0,3----->returns 1  , N=5 values are: 2,3,4,0,3---->returns 0.

Comment: maybe `O(n*log(n))` with quicksort then it's trivial

Comment: The sorting problem I already solved, But is there any real way to get the answer in O(n)

Comment: Are we allowed to destroy the original array?

Comment: @bitmask, where will you store the values? since you cant use subarray....

Comment: I get it: that's a joke from your teacher (homework?). It's impossible to get `O(n)` _and_ no auxiliary buffer. someone prove me wrong and get a bounty

Comment: This is a bonus question in my homework. I also start to think that this is just impossible I tried for 3 days to solve this problem, But let's wait maybe someone does have an answer.

Comment: if you find that, your teacher is going to get a Nobel from your work :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre You only need N bits of auxiliary space, and the input array will typically have 32*N bits. So as long as N is less than 2 billion, it's easy.

Comment: yeah, using the extra bits & masking... nice. that's cheating, but nice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're allowed to modify the input array, the problem can be solved in O(N).

Observations:

1. If the array was sorted, the problem would be trivial.
2. Sorting an array 0...N-1 where values are also 0...N-1 is also trivial, since each element's position is its value, you can iterate once, swapping elements into their final position.

Just need an additional check during swapping that the element at position *i* doesn't already have the value *i*, which would mean *i* appears twice in the array.

```
int check(unsigned* a, unsigned size) {
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        unsigned b = a[i];
        if (b != i) {
            do {
                if (b < 0 || b >= size)
                    return false; // value out of range
                unsigned c = a[b];
                if (b == c)
                    return false; // duplicate value
                a[b] = b;
                b = c;
            } while (b != i);
            a[i] = i;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Note that the the inner loop makes the solution look O(N<sup>2</sup>), but it's not - each element is visited at most twice. The inner loop is needed to resolve cycles as in `{1,2,3,0}`.

Comment: the best solution because it can even be done with unsigned, and doesn't hide any data with signs, overflow...

Comment: You have a buffer overrun, because b is not checked for validity. E.g. {0,2,3}.

Comment: I think you can fix this by splitting the loop into two loops.

Comment: @rustyx please explain what is the variable end for? and what was the issue with the previous one?

Comment: It seems you did not use the end variable, and could you explain what is the logic in your new solution since it looks harder to understand.

Comment: Ah right, end isn't needed after all. It was left over from my intermediate version where I incremented `i` inside the inner loop. The performance benefit of that seems negligible so I removed it.

Comment: `b < 0` seems useless since `b` is unsigned.

Answer (score 3):

This is my version. It runs in O(n).

The idea is to manipulate the original array and add N to it in order to mark all values that have been encountered. Then we do a sweep and check that all values are greater or equal than N and change the value back to the original one.

The only caveat is that the array must be mutable.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int check(unsigned* a, size_t size) {
  for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    if (a[i] >= size) {
      return 0;
    }   
  }
  for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    size_t const x = a[i] % size;
    a[x] = x + size;
  }
  int result = 1;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    if (a[i] < size) {
      result = 0;
    } else {
      a[i] = a[i] - size;
    }   
  }
  return result;
}


int main() {
  unsigned a1[] = {0,5,1,3,2,4};
  unsigned a2[] = {0,5,1,3,0,0};
  printf("a1: %d\n",check(a1,sizeof(a1)/sizeof(*a1)));
  printf("a2: %d\n",check(a2,sizeof(a2)/sizeof(*a2)));
}
```

Comment: @user3386109 Correct. It can overflow. But if you use a large enough data type (eg. unsigned long) iterating over it is impossible anyway. So in practice, it still works.

Comment: it's the only way :) that makes the problem less interesting, though.

Answer (score 2):

All values are positive, so we can exploit the bit sign for our purposes.

Iterate over the array; for each element, check if it's negative, if so negate it and subtract 1. If it's outside the valid range [0, N-1] of course the input array is not valid, although you say we don't have to worry about this.

If it's in the range, use it as an index in the array itself; if the value you find is positive make it negative and subtract 1. If it's negative, it means that there's a duplicate element (you already sign-swapped it).

(the "subtract 1" thing is to account for the 0, which remains the same when negated)

Due to the pigeonhole principle, if you get to the last element without duplicates and without out of ranges, the input array contains all and only the elements in the range [0, N-1]. If you feel bad about leaving the array all negative, you can do a last pass to flip the sign of every number.

```
bool check(int *arr, int N) {
    bool ret = true;
    for(int i = 0; i < N && ret; ++i) {
        int v = arr[i];
        if(v < 0) v = -v - 1;
        if(v >= N || arr[v] < 0) ret = false;
        else arr[v] = -arr[v] - 1;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) { 
        if(arr[i] < 0) arr[i] = -arr[i] - 1;
    } 
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: "If it's in the range, look it up in the array itself,": then it's no longer `O(n)` it's `O(n*2)`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre array indexing is O(1)! I'll try to express it better.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I meant straight indexing. See if it's clearer now.

Comment: yeah, got it. Nice.

Comment: This is a nice solution.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Yes, but the second time one would/should exit/return 0?

Comment: Instead of using sign and abs, one could just flip the first bit directly using a ... ehm ... bitmask :)

Comment: @Danny_ds my bad. But the multiple zero case kills the fun. That said, it's easy to add 1 to all elements first.

Comment: @bitmask of course, but this was meant to avoid thinking about the type size, what bit to use, etc. For the zeroes, indeed I should add one when negating and fix the rest of the code. Or even simpler, subtract N.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: O(n*2) is O(n).