# A function that returns 0 or 1 if all elements in the range 0 to n-1 exist in the array, run time O(n)

Tags: c, arrays

EDIT:
I forgot to mention that I do not want to allocate another temporarily array.

I am trying to solve a problem in C, which is:
Suppose you were given an array a and it's size N. You know that all of the elements in the array are between 0 to n-1. The function is supposed to return 0 if there is a missing number in the range (0 to n-1). Otherwise, it returns 1. As you can understand, duplicates are possible. The thing is that its supposed to run on O(n) runtime.
I think I managed to do it but i'm not sure. From looking at older posts here, it seems almost impossible and the algorithm seems much more complicated then the algorithm  I have. Therefore, something feels wrong to me. 
I could not find an input that returns the wrong output yet thou.

In any case, I'd appreciate your feedback- or if you can think of an input that this might not work for.  Here's the code:

```
int missingVal(int* a, int size)
{
  int i, zero = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    //We multiply the element of corresponding index by -1
    a[abs(a[i])] *= -1;

  for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
  {
     //If the element inside the corresponding index is positive it means it never got multiplied by -1 
     //hence doesn't exist in the array
     if (a[i] > 0)
       return 0;

     //to handle the cases for zeros, we will count them
     if (a[i] == 0)
       zero++;
  }
  if (zero != 1)
    return 0;

  return 1;
}
```

Comment: You don't cite what other answers you looked at. But it's worth pointing out that you require write access to the array. Most functions that answer questions about data treat the data as `const`. This would mean allocating your own array, as several (deleted) answers have suggested. Might this be why the other answers seem complicated?

Comment: Hey, sorry. Here for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54491474/finding-an-elements-within-a-range-using-on-runtime

Comment: I have edited the post - I do not want to allocate another array

Comment: @Cocoboom "I forgot to mention that I do not want to allocate another temporarily array." is poor SO etiquette to change the post. Once answers (and good ones too) came in to answer the question well, you changed the rules. AFAIK, you'll keep changing. This makes the question  a moving target and not clear.  VTC.  Suggest to roll back your question.  Accept a good answer and if still needing, post a new -more precise question.

Answer (score 2):

your program works and it is in O(N), but it is quite complicated and worst it modify the initial array

can be just that :

```
int check(int* a, int size)
{
  int * b = calloc(size, sizeof(int));
  int i;

  for (i = 0; i != size; ++i) {
    b[a[i]] = 1;
  }

  for (i = 0; i != size; ++i) {
    if (b[i] == 0) {
      free(b);
      return 0;
    }
  }

  free(b);
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: @mkrieger1 oupps is a typo, must be size of course, thank you for warning me

Comment: @bruno Thank you for your help! I forgot to mention that I do not want to use another array. Edited now.

Answer (score 2):

Just copy the values to another array placing each value in its ordinal position. Then walk the copy to see if anything is missing.

Comment: Also known as sorting the array

Answer (score 2):

This problem is the **same** as finding out if your **array has duplicates**. Here's why

1. All the numbers in the array are between `0` and `n-1`
2. The array has a size of `n`

If there's a missing number in that range, that can only mean that another number took its place. Which means that the array must have a duplicate number

## An algorithm in O(n) time & O(1) space

1. Iterate through your array
2. If the sign of the current number is positive, then make it negative
3. If you found a negative this means that you have a duplicate. Since all items are originally greater (or equal) than 0

## Implementation

```
int missingVal(int arr[], int size)
{
    // Increment all the numbers to avoid an array with only 0s
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) arr[i]++;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (arr[abs(arr[i])] >= 0)
            arr[abs(arr[i])] = -arr[abs(arr[i])];
        else
            return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

## Edit

As [Bruno](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2458991/bruno) mentioned if we have an array with all zeros, we could have run into a problem. This is why I included in this *edit* an incrementation of all the numbers.

While this add another "pass" into the algorithm, the solution is **still in O(n) time & O(1) space**

## Edit #2

Another great suggestion from Bruno which optimizes this, is to look if there's more than one zero instead of incrementing the array.

If there's 2 or more, we can directly return `0` since we have found a duplicate (and by the same token that not all the numbers in the range are in the array)

Comment: if your array only contains 0 that doesn't work ;), you just need to add the check of the number of zeros (when reach 2 return 0. Is simpler that OP anyway.

Comment: I haven't thought of that, nice catch! I think if we increment all numbers by one, we can avoid this case (we'll have all 1s which is good). Editing my answer, thanks

Comment: if you start by incrementing you read (and write) 1 times more in the vector, is useless, and that complexify. up voted ^^

Comment: Thanks! You're right, it will add another iteration but it will stay in O(n) time and O(1) space though

Comment: As you say, checking the number of zeros is even better. Editing again

Comment: yes complexity unchanged, but less pure. Just having `int z = 0; for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) { if (arr[abs(arr[i])] > 0) arr[abs(arr[i])] *= -1; else if ((arr[abs(arr[i])] != 0) || (++z == 2)) return 0;` is pure

Comment: or smaller : `int z = 0; for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) { if ((arr[abs(arr[i])] *= -1) < 0) ; else if ((arr[abs(arr[i])] != 0) || (++z == 2)) return 0;`

Answer (score 0):

To overcome the requirement that excludes any extra memory consumption, the posted algorithm changes the values inside the array by simply negating their value, but that would leave index 0 unchanged.

I propose a different mapping: from [0, size) to (**-1 - size**, **-1**], so that e.g. {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ...} becomes {-1, -2, -3, -4, -5, ...}. Note that, for a two's complement representation of integers, INT_MIN = -INT_MAX - 1.

```
//  The following assumes that every value inside the array is in [0, size-1)
int missingVal(int* a, int size)      // OT: I find the name misleading
{
    int i = 0;
    for (; i < size; i++)
    {
        int *pos = a[i] < 0
            ? a + (-a[i] - 1)  // A value can already have been changed...
            : a + a[i];

        if ( *pos < 0 )        // but if the pointed one is negative, there's a duplicate
            break;

        *pos = -1 - *pos;
    }

    return i == size;         // Returns 1 if there are no duplicates 
}
```

If needed, the original values could be restored, before returning, with a simple loop

```
if ( i != size ) {
    for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j) {
        if ( a[j] < 0 )
            a[j] = -a[j] - 1;
    }
} else {                             // I already know that ALL the values are changed
    for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j)
        a[j] = -a[j] - 1;
}
```